# How can I fill a Color[] from a Texture2D given a Rectangle in SharpDX?

Tags: xna, c#, textures, sharpdx

I used to fill a `Color[]` using XNA's

```
Texture2D.GetData<T>(int, Rectangle?, T[], int, int)
```

method, but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent overload on SharpDX's `Texture2D`. Anyone know how I can get this same functionality with SharpDX?

**EDIT**

How can I fill a `Color[]` from a `SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics.Texture2D` given a `Rectangle` in SharpDX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharpDX is a *DirectX* wrapper, not an XNA one. XNA's `GetData` methods are higher-level abstractions on top of the underlying DirectX functionality.

If you're using the D3D9 interface, you probably want a variant of [`LockRectangle`](http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/m-sharpdx-direct3d9-texture-lockrectangle). If you're using D3D11 you probably want some variant of [`MapSubresource`](http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/m-sharpdx-direct3d11-devicecontext-mapsubresource-6) (or the similar method for D3D10). Note that in D3D9 the operation is a method of the texture, but in 10 and 11 it's a method of device context.

Comment: I suppose I should have rephrased my question. My question is basically how can I fill a `Color` array from a `Texture2D` given a `Rectangle` in SharpDX? This is DX11

Comment: Once you have called "MapSubresource," the output DataStream will contain the texture data. You can read it directly from the DataStream or copy it to a raw color array using the methods of the DataStream object (such as Read).

Comment: Is it possible to do it on the `GraphicsDevice` object instead of having to cast the `GraphicsDevice` to a `DeviceContext` (which I'm told is not recommended)?

Comment: No, [ID3D11Device](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476379(v=vs.85).aspx) does not have the method. A device and a context are not the same thing, you can't cast them around. You should already have a context around (at least the immediate context) since you can't generate rendering commands without it.